# Java :send many items from a database via Mail

Tags: email, jakarta-mail

```
public void sendMail( List<problem> listproblem) {

    try {
        ......

        EmailMessage msg = new EmailMessage(emailService);  
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("../../../../../email_template/mail_template.html")));   
        StringBuilder stb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = "";


        for (int item = 1; item < listproblem.size(); item++) {
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

                if (line.contains("--Costumer--")) {
                    line = line.replace("--Costumer--", listproblem.get(item).getCustomer().getName());
                }

                if (line.contains("--Country--")) {
                    line = line.replace("--Country--", listproblem.get(item).getCustomer().getCountry().getName());
                }

                if (line.contains("--issue--")) {
                    line = line.replace("--issue--", listproblem.get(item).getName());
                }   

                if (line.contains("--Summary--")) {
                    line = line.replace("--Summary--", listproblem.get(item).getSummary());
                }  

                if (line.contains("--severity--")) {

                    if (listIssue.get(item).getPriority().contains("1")) {
                        line = line.replace("--severity--", "<label style=\"color:orange;\">Priority 1</label>");
                    }else{
                        line = line.replace("--severity--","<label style=\"color:#DF0101;\">Priority 0</label>");
                    }
                }
                stb.append(line).append("\n");
            }
            //stb.append(stb).append("\n");    

        }
    }
```

Comment: Please clarify what "only one record is added to the mail template." E.g. show some output and explain what's expected.

Comment: Corrected indentation of code to ease readability.

Comment: There's some code but no description of the problem.  What are you trying to do?  What happens when you use the code above?  What do you want to happen?  Note that the code above creates a bunch of text in a StringBuilder but then never uses it.